# How to let xz show percentage progress when compressing block device in Linux?

Tags: linux, block-device, xz

When I use xz to compress a block device (e.g. `/dev/sda1`), `--verbose` shows the current size read from input file (128 MiB below). However, it does not show the percentage of input file read (`--- %` on the left). Is it possible to give xz a hint about the size of this device, so that it can show the percentage? For example, when compressing a normal file xz shows `0.7 %` below.

```
$ sudo xz -1ck --verbose /dev/sda1 > /dev/null
/dev/sda1 (1/1)
  --- %        12.2 MiB / 128.0 MiB = 0.095    21 MiB/s       0:06             
^C
$ sudo xz -1ck --verbose a_normal_file > /dev/null
a_normal_file (1/1)
  0.7 %         11.6 MiB / 12.7 MiB = 0.916   2.3 MiB/s       0:05             
^C
$
```

Answer (score 0):

`xz` has no ability to see the size of partitions since they are not ordinary files, and will therefore not report on it.

What you could do though, is process it with `dd if=/dev/sda1 status=progress | xz -1k --verbose > /dev/null`. You won't get the `xz` details though. What you would have to do is redirect the output of each to separate `tty`'s or files and `tail` them.

Answer (score 0):

Partition size (kibibytes) could be gotten from `/proc/partitions`, then the `dd` output could be passed through `pv`, like this:

```bash
$ kb=$(grep $(basename /dev/sdb1) /proc/partitions | awk '{print $3}')
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 | pv -s ${kb}K | xz -1k >/dev/null
72,2MiO 0:00:20 [2,58MiB/s] [========>                         ] 28% ETA 0:00:49
```